# Receiving garbage data from serial port

Tags: qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm using serial port class for transferring data from machine to machine. Before I open the port I define the following settings:

```
Port = new QSerialPort(this);
    Port ->setPortName("COM16");
    Port ->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    Port ->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    Port ->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    Port ->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    Port ->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    Port ->clear();
```

My problem is, that sometimes when I run my app I get from the Serial port  garbage data, the issue gets fixed when I open ExtraPutty tool (http://www.extraputty.com/download.php) on the same port- I get their the correct data and afterwards when I open my application everything is OK and I receive normal data. Probably the ExtraPutty defines some setting that I missed and the settings stays when I open the port from my application.
can some one help me figure out what is the issue?

Comment: If you are working in Windows, use portmon to see serial port parameters: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx